# Can not use attribute unavailable in derived class when superclass uses the same

Tags: swift

The compiler rejects the code below:

```
class A : NSObject {

    @available(*, unavailable, message="init is not a supported initializer for this class.")
    override init () {

    }

}

class B : A {

    @available(*, unavailable, message="init is not a supported initializer for this class.")
    override init () {

    }

}
```

with the following error:

> Cannot override 'init' which has been marked unavailable.

How do I mark both both super and derived class's initializer as unavailable knowing that removing override brings the missing override error?

Comment: I'm having, currently, a similar problem where I want to mock objects that have an "unavailable" initialiser. If you know more about this subject I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid your avatar pretty much sum up my answer: you can't.

You can talk about it on the swift evolution forum:

https://lists.swift.org/mailman/listinfo/swift-evolution

Meanwhile, you could just mark the B class method as unavailable, and the A one as deprecated.